# Why is Theta4_1 giving the wrong quadrant in C# while everything else correct?

Tags: c#, linear-algebra, robotics

How can I adjust Theta 4_1 which should return 0 rather than 180? What is causing the result to go in the wrong quadrant in C#. Everything else works fine, therefore in the codes provided below theta 4_1 is the main focus. I've checked a few documentations but still can't figure it out. I'll appreciate some guidance. Thanks in advance. ** This is already worked out in MATLAB, hence I know what values that should be returned.**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace IK
{
    class Inverse

    {
        static void Main()
        {
            {
                //Link lenghts & Offsets in Millimeters(mm)
                double a2 = 380.0; double a3 = 0.0; double d3 = 0.0; double d4 = 351.0; double L5 = 89.00;
 
                //End Effector points at **home position**

                double p1x = 362.50;
                double p1y = 12.50;
                double p1z = -420;

                double p2x = 397.50;
                double p2y = 12.50;
                double p2z = -420;

                double p3x = 362.50;
                double p3y = -12.50;
                double p3z = -420;

                double p4x = 362.50;
                double p4y = 12.50;
                double p4z = -432;

                // Tool tip points
                double epx = 380.00; double epy = 0.00; double epz = -440.00;
                //double epx = X; double epy = Y; double epz = Z;

                // M points computation nx ny nz
                double nx = (p2x - p1x) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p2x - p1x, 2) + Math.Pow(p2y - p1y, 2) + Math.Pow(p2z - p1z, 2));
                //Console.WriteLine("nx = "+ nx);
                double ny = (p2y - p1y) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p2x - p1x, 2) + Math.Pow(p2y - p1y, 2) + Math.Pow(p2z - p1z, 2));
                //Console.WriteLine("ny = " + ny);
                double nz = (p2z - p1z) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p2x - p1x, 2) + Math.Pow(p2y - p1y, 2) + Math.Pow(p2z - p1z, 2));
                //Console.WriteLine("nz = " + nz);

                // M points computation sx sy sz
                double sx = (p3x - p1x) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p3x - p1x, 2) + Math.Pow(p3y - p1y, 2) + Math.Pow(p3z - p1z, 2));
                //Console.WriteLine("sx = " + sx);
                double sy = (p3y - p1y) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p3x - p1x, 2) + Math.Pow(p3y - p1y, 2) + Math.Pow(p3z - p1z, 2));
                //Console.WriteLine("sy = " + sy);
                double sz = (p3z - p1z) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p3x - p1x, 2) + Math.Pow(p3y - p1y, 2) + Math.Pow(p3z - p1z, 2));
                //Console.WriteLine("sz = " + sz);

                // M points computation ax ay az
                double ax = (p4x - p1x) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p4x - p1x, 2) + Math.Pow(p4y - p1y, 2) + Math.Pow(p4z - p1z, 2));
                //Console.WriteLine("ax = " + ax);
                double ay = (p4y - p1y) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p4x - p1x, 2) + Math.Pow(p4y - p1y, 2) + Math.Pow(p4z - p1z, 2));
                //Console.WriteLine("ay = " + ay);
                double az = (p4z - p1z) / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(p4x - p1x, 2) + Math.Pow(p4y - p1y, 2) + Math.Pow(p4z - p1z, 2));
                //Console.WriteLine("az = " + az);

                // End points calulations
                double px = epx - ax * L5;
                //Console.WriteLine("px = " + px);
                double py = epy - ay * L5;
                //Console.WriteLine("py = " + py);
                double pz = epz - az * L5;
                //Console.WriteLine("pz = " + pz);

                // Trigonometric substitution using element (2,4)
                double p1 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(px, 2) + Math.Pow(py, 2)); // Rho value in the manuscript for theta 1
                //Console.WriteLine("p1 = " + p1);
                double p3 = Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(d4, 2) + Math.Pow(a3, 2)); // Rho value in the manuscript for theta 3
                //Console.WriteLine("p3 = " + p3);

                // Finding joint angle 1 
                double theta1_1 = Math.Atan2(py, px) - Math.Atan2(d3/p1, Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(1 - (d3/p1),2)));                
                double theta1_2 = Math.Atan2(py, px) - Math.Atan2(d3/p1, -Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(1 - (d3/p1),2)));

                // Finding joint angle 3 
                double K = Math.Pow(px, 2) + Math.Pow(py, 2) + Math.Pow(pz, 2) - Math.Pow(a3,2) - Math.Pow(d4, 2) 
                         - Math.Pow(a2, 2) - Math.Pow(d3, 2) / (2*a2);
                //Console.WriteLine("K = " + K);

                double theta3_1 = Math.Atan2(a3, d4) - Math.Atan2(K/p3, Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(1 - (K / p3), 2)));
                double theta3_2 = Math.Atan2(a3, d4) - Math.Atan2(K/p3, -Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(1 - (K / p3), 2)));

                // Finding joint angle 2 
                // Theta2_1
                double s23_1 = ((-a2 * Math.Cos(theta3_1) - a3) * pz + (a2 * Math.Sin(theta3_1) - d4) * 
                               (px * Math.Cos(theta1_1) + py * Math.Sin(theta1_1))); //Y in our formula
                double c23_1 = ((a2 * Math.Sin(theta3_1) - d4) * pz + (a2 * Math.Cos(theta3_1) + a3) * 
                               (px * Math.Cos(theta1_1) + py * Math.Sin(theta1_1))); //X in our formula
                double theta23_1 = Math.Atan2(s23_1, c23_1);
                double theta2_1 = (theta23_1 - theta3_1);               

                // Theta2_2
                double s23_2 = ((-a2 * Math.Cos(theta3_2) - a3) * pz + (a2 * Math.Sin(theta3_2) - d4) *
                               (px * Math.Cos(theta1_1) + py * Math.Sin(theta1_1))); //Y in our formula
                double c23_2 = ((a2 * Math.Sin(theta3_2) - d4) * pz + (a2 * Math.Cos(theta3_2) + a3) *
                               (px * Math.Cos(theta1_1) + py * Math.Sin(theta1_1))); //X in our formula
                double theta23_2 = Math.Atan2(s23_2, c23_2);
                double theta2_2 = (theta23_2 - theta3_2);               

                // Theta2_3
                double s23_3 = ((-a2 * Math.Cos(theta3_1) - a3) * pz + (a2 * Math.Sin(theta3_1) - d4) *
                               (px * Math.Cos(theta1_2) + py * Math.Sin(theta1_2))); //Y in our formula
                double c23_3 = ((a2 * Math.Sin(theta3_1) - d4) * pz + (a2 * Math.Cos(theta3_1) + a3) *
                               (px * Math.Cos(theta1_2) + py * Math.Sin(theta1_2))); //X in our formula
                double theta23_3 = Math.Atan2(s23_3, c23_3);
                double theta2_3 = (theta23_3 - theta3_1);

                // Theta2_4
                double s23_4 = ((-a2 * Math.Cos(theta3_2) - a3) * pz + (a2 * Math.Sin(theta3_2) - d4) *
                               (px * Math.Cos(theta1_2) + py * Math.Sin(theta1_2))); //Y in our formula
                double c23_4 = ((a2 * Math.Sin(theta3_2) - d4) * pz + (a2 * Math.Cos(theta3_2) + a3) *
                               (px * Math.Cos(theta1_2) + py * Math.Sin(theta1_2))); //X in our formula
                double theta23_4 = Math.Atan2(s23_4, c23_4);
                double theta2_4 = (theta23_4 - theta3_2);

                // Finding joint angle 4 
                // Theta4_1
                double s4_1 = Math.Cos(theta1_1) * ay - Math.Sin(theta1_1) * ax ; //Y
                 //Console.WriteLine($"s4_1 = {s4_1:f64}"); // Checking s4_1
                double c4_1 = -Math.Cos(theta1_1) * Math.Cos(theta23_1) * ax - Math.Sin(theta1_1) *
                               Math.Cos(theta23_1) * ay + Math.Sin(theta23_1) * az;//X
                //Console.WriteLine($"c4_1 = {c4_1:f64}"); // Checking s4_1
                double theta4_1 = Math.Atan2(s4_1, c4_1); //negate X to get the value of the second quadrant 

                // Theta4_2
                double s4_2 = Math.Cos(theta1_1) * ay - Math.Sin(theta1_1) * ax;
                double c4_2 = -Math.Cos(theta1_1) * Math.Cos(theta23_2) * ax - Math.Sin(theta1_1) *
                               Math.Cos(theta23_2) * ay + Math.Sin(theta23_2) * az;
                double theta4_2 = Math.Atan2(s4_2, c4_2);

                // Theta4_3
                double s4_3 = Math.Cos(theta1_2) * ay - Math.Sin(theta1_2) * ax;
                double c4_3 = -Math.Cos(theta1_2) * Math.Cos(theta23_3) * ax - Math.Sin(theta1_2) *
                               Math.Cos(theta23_3) * ay + Math.Sin(theta23_3) * az;
                double theta4_3 = Math.Atan2(s4_3, c4_3);

                // Theta4_4
                double s4_4 = Math.Cos(theta1_2) * ay - Math.Sin(theta1_2) * ax;
                double c4_4 = -Math.Cos(theta1_2) * Math.Cos(theta23_4) * ax - Math.Sin(theta1_2) *
                               Math.Cos(theta23_4) * ay + Math.Sin(theta23_4) * az;
                double theta4_4 = Math.Atan2(s4_4, c4_4);

                //Converting  from radians to degrees & Display

                //theta 1
                Console.WriteLine("theta1_1  = " + theta1_1 * 180 / (Math.PI));
                Console.WriteLine("theta1_2  = " + theta1_2 * 180 / (Math.PI));

                //thetha 3
                Console.WriteLine("theta3_1  = " + theta3_1 * 180 / (Math.PI));
                Console.WriteLine("theta3_2  = " + theta3_2 * 180 / (Math.PI));

                //theta 2
                Console.WriteLine("theta2_1  = " + theta2_1 * 180 / (Math.PI));
                Console.WriteLine("theta2_2  = " + theta2_2 * 180 / (Math.PI));
                Console.WriteLine("theta2_3  = " + theta2_3 * 180 / (Math.PI));
                Console.WriteLine("theta2_4  = " + theta2_4 * 180 / (Math.PI));

                //theta 4
                Console.WriteLine("theta4_1  = " + theta4_1 * 180 / (Math.PI));
                Console.WriteLine("theta4_2  = " + theta4_2 * 180 / (Math.PI));
                Console.WriteLine("theta4_3  = " + theta4_3 * 180 / (Math.PI));
                Console.WriteLine("theta4_4  = " + theta4_4 * 180 / (Math.PI));

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJcsv.png)

[Comparison of the results gained from C#, MATLAB & Python](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JFrlh.png)

Comment: Could you include a picture or schematic of what the links should look like?

Comment: did so, check update.

Comment: Why would you declare C# to be the one in the wrong when [Matlab says it has a non-compliant implementation](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html#bucvbr8-4)?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever wow, good catch, I was just reading up on robotics and inverse kinematics to find the mathematical mistake but I guess it was just that easy.

Comment: I understand but I am not sure if 180 will yield the same results as 0 further on, because it is the opposite quadrant. Let's stick on this, as I think it's a good problem to have. I will continue to write the program and I'll update you guys on my results. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. Also, @JansthcirlU, you can share your findings as well. Cheers!

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I think it's wrong because I've already run a simulation using the MATLAB results and it works quite well. Now its a matter of writing the program using C#.  As I said prior, a good problem to have. (A lot to discover from this).

Comment: After discovering what Damien_The_Unbeliever said about " Matlab is non-compliant implementation". I went ahead and wrote the code in Python, the results are the same as C#. You can take a look at the photo I added to compare the findings. Thank you,

Comment: I'm afraid I can't be of more help, it really does seem that your calculations are correct and that Matlab simply uses a different implementation. However, what I can recommend as a developer is to write methods that calculate things for you instead of repeating the calculations manually. A bit of object oriented programming could also help you in making abstractions (e.g. using a `Coordinate` class instead of using x, y, z values separately).

Answer (score 0):

MATLAB's atan2 has a few behaviors that differ from those of IEEE®-754 Standard.

[image: IEEE®-754 Standard vs MATLAB]

Source: [atan2, MATLAB's page](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/atan2.html#bucvbr8-4)